# How to build Qt for Windows?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to get Qt working for Windows. I am starting at: https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#Getting_the_source_code.

I could clone the Git repository, but nothing works then:

```sh
..\\qt5\configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

It brings me error on command not found:

```
   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (../qt5/configure:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The files configure and configure.bat exist in the right place...
Running nmake brings an error on a missing makefile...

I didn't see there was a binary and I installed it.
Now, in QtCreator, I have another problem. I try to add a new empty project, and when I must enter a kit I got this:
capture:
[image: capture]

What must I do? I can't select anyone.

After reinstalling Qt, I could find the kits, but when I compile a simple program:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    return app.exec();
}
```

I got this error:

```
MSVCRTD.lib(exe_winmain.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol  WinMain r‚f‚renc‚ in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
```

Finally adding CONFIG += console to the .pro file fixed the issue.

Comment: What compiler are you using, are you using cmake too? Please be more precise.

Comment: looks like you aren't following the windows instructions, use back slashes instead of forward ones

Comment: No, I used the correct syntax, it is a mistake on my copy/paste code, I am sorry.

Comment: I use: ..\\qt5\configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests. I Don't know how I can be more precise, I don't use cmake, I just follow the instructions on the qt link. And nothing work.

Comment: What is your subsystem is it Subsytem:Windows or Subsystem:Console? Using ```main()``` implies the usage of Subsystem:Console or ```mainCRTStartup```.

Comment: CONFIG += console to the .pro file fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Here are the commands I use to compile Qt5 under Windows (you'll need to update the paths and options to suit your situation of course):

```
cd C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.xx.y
configure -prefix %CD%\qtbase -opensource -nomake tests -nomake examples
nmake
```

(On the very latest versions of Qt, e.g. 5.15.4, you can call jom instead of nmake in order to get a faster compile)

Comment: Thank you, I found the binary to install but I have a little problem as I mentioned above